# How to map POST parameters to model object using spring MVC method

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, multipartform-data

I have a form that contains a file and some other input field elements.
Submit is done as follows:

```
var xhrArgs = {
          form: attachmentForm,
          handleAs: "json",
          load: dojo.hitch(this, this._uploadSuccess),
          error: dojo.hitch(this, this._uploadError)
        };

var deferred =  dojo.io.iframe.send(xhrArgs);
```

On backend i have a Spring controller listening for this POST request as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadAttachment.spr", consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

Everything works fine so far.

I would like now to get all request parameters (basically the POST payload) inside a POJO object.

I tried adding a @RequestBody parameter, but it fails with bad request(400):

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadAttachment.spr", consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
 @RequestBody AttachmentFormModel model)
```

I assume it fails because the payload is not in JSON format.

So my question is: what is the best way to automatically map all request parameters into a model object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this using @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestBody